# How do I dynamically change the image content of a kendo ui window using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have a kendo listview full of thumbnail images.  On double-click, a javascript function is called and opens up a kendo ui window.  The window comes up fine; however, the image does not show up in the window.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
function ShowImage(img) {
    alert(img.src);     //=== Image source is displayed correctly on the alert
    var wimg = $("#imageWindow").data("kendoWindow");
    wimg.open();
    wimg.content("<img src='" + img.src + "' />");
    //wimg.refresh();   //=== tried this but it didn't seem to make a difference.
}
```

No error is thrown that I can see.  The window just comes up blank.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Also tried variations:

```
function ShowImage(img) {
    alert(img.src);     //=== Image source is displayed correctly on the alert
    var wimg = $("#imageWindow").data("kendoWindow");
    wimg.content("<img src='" + img.src + "' />");
    wimg.open();
}
```

Also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you shared looks completely valid to me. Check [this out](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@pesho/AxEW).

Comment: Thanks a ton.  I was an idiot and omitted a semicolon from the actual code but fixed it for this post.. haha.